# Gitolite - Can a key file have and @ sign in it

Tags: gitosis, public-key

I have a few public key files in my keydir/ some are named like this user@host.pub

In my config file I specify the user as user@host, but when I try and push the changes, I get this warning

```
remote: 
remote:         ***** WARNING *****
remote:         the following users (pubkey files in parens) do not appear in the config file:
remote: user(user@host.pub)
```

Anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding, probably not. Since the '@' needs to be escaped.

I usually generate my keys using the following:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C userName -f userName
```

...so that I don't run into this issue.